# Recirculating mash through screen

Tags: mash, rims

Is it possible to continously recirculate a mash through a Bazooka-style screen, or is that just asking for a stuck mash due to the relatively small surface area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend in my brew club does this exact thing in his electric set up and has never had any issues. 100's of gallons of beer brewed, and no hiccups.

Though, when dealing with high adjunct mashes, I would be extra careful and take whatever preventative measures you can (i.e. addition of rice hulls, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I use a pump to recirculate through a hose braid.  A Bazooka is more open than that so it shouldn't be a problem.